# Is it possible to make methods only available in specialized instances of a class/type constructor?

Tags: scala, generics, types, infix-notation

I want to implement a wrapper class, which has different methods available, depending on the type it wraps.

I have something like this in mind:

```
case class Wrapper[A](val : A)

case class Wrapper[A : Numeric](val a : A) {
    def add[A](a : A) = new Wrapper(this.a + a)
}

val a = new Wrapper(1.0)
val b = new Wrapper(2.0)
val c = a add b
val d = new Wrapper(new Object)

val e = a add d // Compile Error!
```

I have already found out, that I could restrict the passed parameter with the *Type Class*-Pattern, but this could obviously lead to errors, when the type of `this` is not restricted.

Is this even possible in the scala type system? Any type safe pattern to achieve similiar results (the infix Notation is important here) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may add this kind of constraint directly to the method `add`:

```
case class Wrapper[A](value : A){
  def add(other : A)(implicit ev : A <%< Numeric[A]) = 
    Wrapper(value.plus( other))
}
```

Calling `add` on an instance where `A` is not `Numeric` will issue compiler error.

(**updated** thanks @AlexIv)

Usage:

```
val a = Wrapper(1.0)
val b = Wrapper(2.0)
val c = a add b
```

Comment: Your version is wrong either cause: 1) defining second type param `A` in `add` is pointless, it's already defined in scope 2) `new Wrapper(value + other)` is wrong and won't compile

Comment: I've fixed it. Instead of [A:Numeric] I should have explicitly declare an evidence parameter with a view (`<%<`) from `A` to `Numeric[A]`.

Comment: When I try to compile this (with the rightmost bracket fixed) I get

`Wrapper.scala:2: error: not found: type <%<
  def add(other : A)(implicit ev : A <%< Numeric[A]) = Wrapper(value + other)
                                     ^
Wrapper.scala:2: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: String
  def add(other : A)(implicit ev : A <%< Numeric[A]) = Wrapper(value + other)`

what's strange is, that I cannot other examples of `<%<`. I'm using scala 2.10 so I guess that featue should be available...

Comment: it seems that `+` method is not in `Numeric`. I've changed it to `plus`.